# Why the getter method of a static field can't be static for the field to be visible?

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I am using Spring Boot and Thymeleaf. I am wondering why do I get the following error if the getter method for a static field is static itself (irregardless of whether the setter is static or not):

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'rb' of bean class [rs.co.UcenikBean]: Bean property 'rb' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?

The field is static and it is accesible only if the getter method is not static.

The code of the class:

```
public class UcenikBean implements Serializable {
    static final long serialVersionUID = 1234L;
    public static Integer rb = 0;
    private String ime;
    private String prezime;
    private char pol;
    private String datumRodjenja;
    private String mejl;
    private int razred;
    private int odeljenje;
    private String bojaOciju;

    public UcenikBean() {
        super();
        idUcenik++;
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

public UcenikBean(String ime, String prezime, char pol, String datumRodjenja, String mejl,
            int razred, int odeljenje, String bojaOciju) {
        super();
        idUcenik++;
        this.ime = ime;
        this.prezime = prezime;
        this.pol = pol;
        this.datumRodjenja = datumRodjenja;
        this.mejl = mejl;
        this.razred = razred;
        this.odeljenje = odeljenje;
        this.bojaOciju = bojaOciju;
    }

    public static Integer getRb() { // rb is not accesible if this is static
        return rb;
    }
    public static void setRb(Integer rb) {
        UcenikBean.rb = rb;
    }
public static long getSerialversionuid() {
        return serialVersionUID;
    }
    public String getIme() {
        return ime;
    }
    public void setIme(String ime) {
        this.ime = ime;
    }
    public String getPrezime() {
        return prezime;
    }
    public void setPrezime(String prezime) {
        this.prezime = prezime;
    }
    public char getPol() {
        return pol;
    }
    public void setPol(char pol) {
        this.pol = pol;
    }
    public String getDatumRodjenja() {
        return datumRodjenja;
    }
    public void setDatumRodjenja(String datumRodjenja) {
        this.datumRodjenja = datumRodjenja;
    }
    public String getMejl() {
        return mejl;
    }
    public void setMejl(String mejl) {
        this.mejl = mejl;
    }
    public int getRazred() {
        return razred;
    }
    public void setRazred(int razred) {
        this.razred = razred;
    }
    public int getOdeljenje() {
        return odeljenje;
    }
    public void setOdeljenje(int odeljenje) {
        this.odeljenje = odeljenje;
    }
    public String getBojaOciju() {
        return bojaOciju;
    }
    public void setBojaOciju(String bojaOciju) {
        this.bojaOciju = bojaOciju;
    }
}
```

Relevant code in my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/lista", "/"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String lista(Model model) {
    UcenikBean x = new UcenikBean("Marko", "Markovic", 'm', new Date(2010, 1, 3), "p@mail.com", 5, 5, "plava");
    listaUcenika.add(x);
    model.addAttribute("listaUcenika", listaUcenika);
    model.addAttribute("ucenikBean", x);
    return "lista";
}

@RequestMapping(value = {"/odabirUcenika"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String ispis(Model model, UcenikBean ucenikBean,
String dodavanje, String menjanje, String brisanje) {
    model.addAttribute("listaUcenika", listaUcenika);
    model.addAttribute("ucenikBean", ucenikBean);
    int x = ucenikBean.getRb();
    return "lista";
}
```

This is the lista page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Lista Učenika</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"
href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO"
crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<form class="form-group" id="formaUcenik" method="POST" action="/odabirUcenika"
            th:action="@{/odabirUcenika}" th:object="${ucenikBean}">

            <select th:if="${! listaUcenika.isEmpty()}" class="form-control" th:field="*{rb}">
            <option th:each="ucenik : ${listaUcenika}"
            th:value="${ucenikStat.index}"
            th:text="${ucenikStat.index} + ' ' + ${ucenik.ime} + ' ' + ${ucenik.prezime}"/>         
            </select>
            <input class="form-control" type="submit" value="Posaljite">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The value that the user inputs should be saved in the 'rb' field and carried over to the next mapping, where it would be printed out to the console, in this example. Please if you could explain, why is the static field 'rb' inaccessible if its getter method is also static?

Comment: Any particular reason you want to keep it static? This being a Spring bean, and unless there is a good reason (a very good infact) non-final public static are bad idea.

Comment: The reason for making it static is because it represents an index number that I use to select the student, so I need this variable on the class level, not one per instance. To be honest I defined the class as a bean just to test it out because I am just learning.

Comment: Can you share missing piece of your code please?

Comment: Yes, I will post the full code of the student class, the html page and the two mappings from the controller now

Comment: Maybe it is better if I modify this example so that the class only contains that 'rb' static field?

Comment: I am trying to confirm something, but the way I see I think thymeleaf wouldn't want anything as static accessor. I am just debugging through the stack.

Comment: com.sun.beans.introspect.PropertyInfo checks if the accessor method is static and then it just don't add property descriptor for that hence it becomes NotReadable for spring context. I am not very close to thymeleaf so not sure what alternatives unfortunately. I will look into this and see if I can find something. I will share here

Comment: Thank you very much for this information! I will have to go now and I will return tomorrow to research this.